# Nginx subfolder redirecting to url with trailing slash

Tags: nginx

This is my setup:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/example.com$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}

if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.html$") {
    return 301 $1;
}

location / {
    root   /var/www/html/example.com;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

When I go to url `https://example.com/subfolder` browser redirects me to `https://example.com/subfolder/` and if I try to remove trailing slash with `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`, there are too many redirects.

Is there a way to remove a trailing slash for subfolders?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately now I get 404 error all the time.

Comment: I want to have a page accessible at url `example.com/subfolder` and I don't want it to have a trailing slash at any point.

Comment: The full path is `/var/www/html/example.com/subfolder/index.html`.

Comment: Change the statement in the `location /` block to: `try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;`

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Is there anything I have to add, if at some point I make another subfolder with `index.php` as root file, instead of `index.html`?

Comment: That's slightly more complicated as the PHP files cannot be processed within the same `location` block. Do you have PHP working and if so, what does your `location ~ \.php$` block look like?

Comment: I do have it working. Added it above.

Comment: Actually it is already working, so thank you!